# Java / Android - How can I know that a variable from any instance of a class is true?

Tags: java, android, instance-variables, instances

This question is not manly for Android, but I will use an android example to explain.
I want to create a class that should override the method `onTouchListener`, to be used on any object that uses those touch methods.
Since after a touch input, the method starts a function, and since it's a class, it can be instantiate several times (and I want to be instantiate several times), I want to prevent that two instances are called at the same time.

I guess I could create a variable inside the class, that assured that if it's true, it can run the method, but I need to check it for all of the class instances.

And since I want to make this a library, I need to do this inside the class itself.

So my question is, 
(Java Question) How can I know that a variable from any instance of a class is true?

(Android Question) Or if this is not possible, How can I prevent multiple touch events at the same time?

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that with static data and/or method for this class. A static element can be accessible from anywhere using the class name:
ex: MyClass.isAlreadyRunning();

you could for example store in an array all the running status of the instances, and create a static method that checks the array if one is already running.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser,
Yes, this could work... The problem is that I want to create a library of the class, and I want to make the comparison inside the class... not forcing other programmer to do it

Got any other ideas?

Comment: there should be no problem, those static elements are also accessible from inside the class itself. The check can be performed at the beginning of the overriden method (see ZeusNet example)

Answer (score 0):

You can think about making a Singleton Class. [Wiki Link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)

Singleton classes allows to create ONLY one instance/object of that class and then reuse it.

Comment: Thank you for your question
The problem is that I want to allow several instances... I just want to prevent them from running at the same time...
Any sugestions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a static field in this context. A static field is identicaly for all instances of an class.

You can do it maybe like this:

```
public Example implements TouchInterface{
    private static boolean actuallyRunning = false;

    public void touchExecute(){
        if(!actuallyRunning){
            actuallyRunning = true;
            callYourFunction();
            actuallyRunning = false;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but How I can I check it inside the class?

If I have several instances of the same class, How I can I check inside the class if the other variables are true?

Comment: Why do you want to check this? With the above code you are preventing multiple touch events at one time. You do not need to check the state for every instance

Comment: Maybe I'm seeing this wrong, but the variable `actuallyRunning`, is only valid for a specific instance... If I create a new instance of the class TouchInterface, the variable with be different, because I only changed for that instance. The variable is not global to all the instances, right?

Comment: No the difference is that this field is defined as static. This means it will be the same instance in each of your class instances

Comment: Ok, but I don't understand how that is gonna help me...  I only check `actuallyRunning` from this instance,  not the all other ones...
Am I seeing this wrong?

Comment: You are only  checking this in one instance, that's right. But as example if you have two instances which wants to execute this method. The first instance is calling it maybe some miliseconds before the second one, it will set the actuallyRunning field to true. If the second instance calls the method it also checks the actuallyRunning field and it's set to true in this case, because the first instance haven't left the method yet. Therefor it's not possible for the second instance to execute the method until the first instance have finished it.

Answer (score 0):

You can use singleton class if you want one one instance and if you want to handle the multiple touch events

1. you can disable as soon as your handler start and enable after that.
2. you can add a time span in normal practice it is one sec but it depends on you handler's complexity

Like this example:

```
// Make ur activity class to implement View.OnClickListener
  public class MenuPricipalScreen extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener{

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
   // setup listeners.
    findViewById(R.id.imageView2).setOnClickListener(MenuPricipalScreen.this);
    findViewById(R.id.imageView3).setOnClickListener(MenuPricipalScreen.this);
    ....
 }

.
.
.
// variable to track event time
private long mLastClickTime = 0;

//View.OnClickListener.onClick method defination

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
// Preventing multiple clicks, using threshold of 1 second
if (SystemClock.elapsedRealtime() - mLastClickTime < 1000) {
    return;
      }
mLastClickTime = SystemClock.elapsedRealtime();

        // Handle button clicks
        if (v == R.id.imageView2) {
    // Do ur stuff.
     }
        else if (v == R.id.imageView2) {
    // Do ur stuff.
     }
        ...
  }
```

.
  .`.

Comment: Thank you for your anwser,
Yes, this should work... The problem is that I want to create a library of the class, and I want to make the comparison inside the class... not forcing other programmer to do it

Got any other ideas?

Comment: Better you static variable for this and use synchronised method to access that.

Answer (score 0):

You should put  "public synchronized" void, so it will prevent to be called in parallel. If you must override, then put a synchronized object in the method so it will do the same.

Comment: Thank you for your answer,
Yes, `synchronized` will indeed prevent the parallel executions, but they will be both executed. I want to ensure that only one is executed

Got any ideas?

Comment: What are the criteria for the second touch to be discarded?

Comment: You can combine synchronized with a static variable and a unique instance identifier:

public class TestClass {
 private static String usedBy;
 private final String instanceId;
 public TestClass(){
  this.instanceId = ((Long)(System.currentTimeMillis())).toString();
 }
 
 public synchronized void ontouch(){
  if(usedBy!=null){
   return;
  }
  usedBy = instanceId;
  // DO YOUR WORK HERE
  usedBy = null;
 }
 public static String getUsedBy(){
  return usedBy;
 }
}